# Copyright act 1976

Tags: copyright

According to the copyright act,

> Limited use of copyright work is permitted on the payment of specified royalties and compliance with statutory conditions.

What does this line mean. I think it states that

> If a buyer pays royalty to the original owner of the work and complies with statutory conditions then use of copyright acts is restricted.

Am I right in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

No. It means that if you pay a royalty to the owner of the copyright, you may use the work in certain ways that comply with the statutory conditions. But, if you do not pay the royalty, you may not use the work at all.